# RegEx for matching all chars except for comma separated digits

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have an input that I want to apply validation to. User can type any integer (positive or negative) numbers separated with a comma. I want to

**Some examples of allowed inputs:**

```
1,2,3
-1,2,-3
3
4
22,-33
```

**Some examples of forbidden inputs:**

```
1,,2
--1,2,3
-1,2,--3
asdas
[]\%$1
```

I know a little about regex, I tried lots of ways, they're not working very well [see this inline regex checker](https://regex101.com/r/SLtuV3/8):

```
^[-|\d][\d,][\d]
```

Comment: Maybe `(?:\W|^)(-?\d+(?:,-?\d+)*)\b` will work for you, or `-?\b\d+(?:,-?\d+)*\b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:-?[0-9]+(?:,(?!$)|$))+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/PAyar7/2

- `-?` - Lead with optional `-`
- `[0-9]+` - Repeat digits
- `(?:,(?!$)|$))` - After the digits, match either a comma, or the end of the string. When matching a comma, make sure you're not at the end of the string with `(?!$)`

Comment: Oh, good point - just negative lookahead for `$` after matching a comma

Comment: Hi! thanks for the great answer. how can I change this regex to allow spaces between  two numbers, something like this: `1,2, 3,  -4, 5,6,7`

Comment: Repeat 0 or more spaces after matching the comma: https://regex101.com/r/PAyar7/3

Comment: Thanks a ton! I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

As per your requirements I'd use something simple like

```
^-?\d+(?:,-?\d+)*$
```

- at start `^` an [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) minus `-?` followed by `\d+` one or more [digits](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html).
- followed by `(?:,-?\d+)*` a [quantified](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) [non capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) containing a comma, followed by an optional hyphen, followed by one or more digits until `$` end.

[See your updated demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SLtuV3/10)

---

Another perhaps harder to understand one which might be a bit less efficient:

```
^(?:(?:\B-)?\d+,?)+\b$
```

- The [quantified](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) [non capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) contains another optional non capturing group with a hyphen preceded by a *non word boundary*, followed by 1 or more digits, followed by optional comma.
- `\b` the [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) at the `$` end ensures, that the string must end with a *word character* (which can only be a digit here).

You can test this one [here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SLtuV3/11)